# How can I install the module gateways and find the adress of my routeur

Tags: 12.04, networking, python-2.7, nmap

I want to determine the address of my router using a python code.
I've found that I can use this method `netifaces.gateways()` after the installation of the `netifaces` library.

But my problem is:

```
rimeh@rimeh-PC:~$ python 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20)     
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2    
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.    
>>> import netifaces    
>>> gws=netifaces.gateways()    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>    
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gateways'
```

I need help,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gateway()` is only available since `netifaces` 0.10.0. Try instead to call the `route` command from a subprocess:

```
$ python -c 'import subprocess; print subprocess.check_output(["route", "-n"]).splitlines()[2].split()[1]'
192.168.1.1
```